# Spring boot elastic search fails on server start up

Tags: java, spring-boot, elasticsearch

we have one spring boot application where we use spring data elastic search. We use entity classes to generate elastic indexes. One such class is shown below -

```
import javax.persistence.Id;

import org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.annotations.Document;
import org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.annotations.Field;
import org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.annotations.FieldType;


/**
 * The Class ElasticSearchSampleEntity.
 */
@Document(indexName = "Sample-index", type = "Sample-content")
public class ElasticSearchSampleEntity {

    /** The es Sample entity id. */
    @Id
    @Field(type = FieldType.Long, index = true, name = "id")
    private Long esSampleEntityId;


    /** The es no of questions. */
    @Field(type = FieldType.Integer, index = true)
    private Integer esNoOfQuestions;

    /** The es total marks. */
    @Field(type = FieldType.Integer, index = true)
    private Integer esTotalMarks;

    /** The es total time min. */
    @Field(type = FieldType.Short, index = true)
    private Short esTotalTimeMin;

    /** The es total time sec. */
    @Field(type = FieldType.Short, index = true)
    private Short esTotalTimeSec;

    /** The es occurances. */
    @Field(type = FieldType.Integer, index = true)
    private Integer esOccurances;


    /** The es rating. */
    @Field(type = FieldType.Float, index = true)
    private Float esRating;


    /** The es created on. */
    @Field(type = FieldType.Long, index = true)
    private Long esCreatedDate;

    /** The es updated on. */
    @Field(type = FieldType.Long, index = true)
    private Long esUpdatedDate;

    /** The es published date. */
    @Field(type = FieldType.Long, index = true)
    private Long publishedDate;

    /** The sample type id. */
    @Field(type = FieldType.Integer, index = true)
    private Integer sampleTypeId;


    //getter and setter

}
```

This should create the index once and store the data to elastic server. However during deployments we are getting the below errors at times (intermittent issues).

```
[main] ERROR o.s.boot.SpringApplication.reportFailure - Application run failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'sampleController': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'esSampleService'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'elasticSearchSampleServiceImpl': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'esSampleRepo'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'elasticSearchSampleRepository': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.repository.support.SimpleElasticsearchRepository]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: mapper [sampleTypeId] cannot be changed from type [long] to [integer]
```

SampleTypeId is getting created(or updated) as Long sometimes even though we specifically mentioned it as Integer. This is what is causing the issue. I have checked data type while saving to elastic db as well which looks fine. Does this mean elastic index is updating with every deployment. For databases we do `spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=validate` similarly for elastic can we do the same? I am not able to understand why this issue is happening. Mapping seems to be fine. Please help me out here.

Answer (score 0):

Below snippet from your error logs is important.

> Constructor threw exception; nested exception is
> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: mapper [sampleTypeId] cannot be
> changed from type [long] to [integer]

Looks like earlier you created the index where your `sampleTypeId` was defined as `long`, and now you are changing this to `int` which is not possible hence the exception is thrown from elasticsearch.

**You can confirm the same from your [elasticsearch GET index mapping API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-get-mapping.html) and inspect the datatype of your `sampleTypeId` in the index.**

Comment: Yes, I have checked the get API. I understand that is the problem. But in my entity class as shown in the question it is mentioned as Integer. I do not understand where and when (and how) it is getting changed to Long.
SampleType Id is defined as Integer it self some how it is getting changed to long at times. Same thing works in some deployments for me. This has got me confused.

Comment: @TheNightsWatch this is strange, by any chance there is any other way mapping of this field is getting change?? I would suggest using the static mapping to avoid any such issues and disable update to mapping if you can.

Comment: Thanks for your time. I am not able to figure out yet where it is getting changed and how to turn off the update to mappings.

Comment: @TheNightsWatch did you check the ES indexing logs to figure out this, anyway I can tell you what the problem and how to fix it, but you need to figure out it from logs :)

Comment: @TheNightsWatch, Hope you are safe, would be great if you can provide an update here :)

Comment: Hello, I have not been able to find out the solution to this. Currently tied up with some other work. I will definitely provide update here once I made a breakthrough. Sorry for the delayed response.

Comment: @TheNightsWatch, Sure